# Create a map from a number of Sets that are an Enum parameter

Tags: java, enums, hashmap, set

I have an Enum which contains 47 constants, and each constant has a `powerSet` defined for it which contains byte numbers.

I would like to create a `Map<Byte, MyEnum>` with a key for every byte in each `Set` that corresponds to my Enum's constants and as a value for each of the keys the Enum constant that the set was from.

So for example if a `VALUE_30` from `MyEnum` has `4, 10, -20, 50` in its set, the map would contain these keys and values:

```
4, VALUE_30
10, VALUE_30
-20, VALUE_30
50, VALUE_30
```

The reason I need to do this is because this Enum is called a lot when my code is running, and having to loop through every constant in the Enum is very performance-heavy.

My Enum looks something like this (summarized and with a bit of pseudo-code):

```java
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE_1(1, 0),
    VALUE_2(2, 16),
    VALUE_3(3, 17),
    VALUE_4(4, 1),
    VALUE_5(5, 116),
    VALUE_6(6, -59),
    VALUE_7(7, 29),
    //... and so on for a total of 47 values
    
    private final int index;
    private final byte byteIndex;
    private final Set<Byte> byteIndexPowerSet;

    MyEnum(int faceIndex, byte byteIndex) {
        this.faceIndex = faceIndex;
        this.byteIndex= byteIndex;
        this.byteIndexPowerSet = //Function of mine that creates the powerSet from the value's params
    }
}
```

Comment: Your enum's constructor takes 2 parameters, yet you are only giving it 1 parameter in each of the enum constants, so the code you posted doesn't compile. Please [edit] your question and fix it. Are you asking about how to create such a map? Also, is the `byteIndexPowerSet` for each enum constant all disjoint from each other? If not, then there would need a multimap.

Comment: So what's the problem exactly? It's a pretty basic loop: `for (MyEnum v : MyEnums.values()) for (Byte b : v.powerSet) map.put(b, v);`

Comment: @Sweeper `byteIndexPowerSet` is unique for each constant

Comment: @shmosel the thing is I'm doing this inside of a specific environment, I've already tried doing what you mentioned, but it resulted in a crash of the program caused by a `NullPointerException` telling me the values of the map were null

Comment: I just tested again, and there was actually a few edge-cases in my Enum that caused the map to return null, so what @shmosel said is actually the easiest way to achieve this in my opinion, I just needed to check if the value I get from the map wasn't null.